# How to recieve an array over Publisher and Subscriber? (Python)

Tags: ros, python, rospy, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Examples would be useful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9471/how-to-recieve-an-array-over-publisher-and-subscriber?-(python)/) by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2011-03-17

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy) might be what you're after. In general, arrays are not much different than anything else--you just need a msg that has an array in it. Suppose e.g. you have a message file, `your_package/Foo.msg`:

```
int32[100] some_integers # array of 100 int32's
float64[] some_floats # variable-sized array of floats
```

Then a publisher would look like:

```
from your_package.msg import Foo
mypub = rospy.Publisher('mytopic', Foo)
msg_to_send = Foo()
msg_to_send.some_integers = range(100)
msg_to_send.some_floats = [1.0, -3.14, 42.0]
mypub.publish(msg_to_send)
```

A subscriber could look like:

```
from your_package.msg import Foo

def mytopic_callback(msg):
    print "Here are some integers:", str(msg.some_integers)
    print "Here are some floats:", str(msg.some_floats)

mysub = rospy.Subscriber('mytopic', Foo, mytopic_callback)
```

This isn't fully working code--you'll need to initialize the nodes, spin, etc but hopefully you get the idea.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-18**:
Thanks! This actually helped me undrstand messages a bit more also.

**Comment by [kk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5289/kk/) on 2013-09-10**:
how to do the same in c++ ?? its tells invalid type even when used std::vector

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-21**:
@kk did you manage to solve it in c++ im have the same problem, thanks

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2013-12-27**:
@kk, @ctguell: this answer might help you guys: http://answers.ros.org/question/60614/how-to-publish-a-vector-of-unknown-length-of-structs-in-ros/